# javascript: how to show value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have this HTML:

```
<form id="my form">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="swim"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="baseball"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="basketball"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="badminton"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="running"/>
</form>
```

And I want to show the result in `<p onclick=""></p>`

How do I type javascript to reveal what I choose in "checkbox"?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You're expected to make **some** effort, do **some** research, before asking other people to do it for you.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="游泳"/>游泳
                      <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="running"/>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="basketball"/>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="baseball"/>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="swimming"/>

Comment: If that comment is an attempt to improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question, not comments.

Comment: Ok. sorry. I'll fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have provided a valid value for id. Instead of "my form", you can put "myform" or whatever but alphanumeric values which can not start with number.

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="swim"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="baseball"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="basketball"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="badminton"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="running"/>
</form>

<p id="pResult" onclick="showCheckedValues(event);"></p>
```

In Javascript you can collect all checkboxes and in `<p>` element put a function which will check, checked checkboxes and place their concated values like

```
<script>

   var checkboxes;
   function showCheckedValues(ev){ 
     var pElement = ev.target;
     if(checkboxes){
       var checkedValues= [];
       checkboxes.forEach(function(x){ 
           if(x.checked){
              checkedValues.push(x.value)
           }
       });
       pElement.innerHTML = checkedValues.join(',');
    }
  }
  window.onload = function(){
     checkboxes =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  }
</script>
```